# Parsing JSON from ReactJS application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to parse a nested json request from my reactjs web app.

Below is the json that I received from a request.

*response.data*

```
{
    "total": 2,
    "offset": 1,
    "limit": 987,
    "staging": [
        {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "Test Stage"
        },
        {
            "id": 102,
            "name": "Dev Stage"
        },
        {
            "id": 103,
            "name": "Prod Stage"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to parse “staging” and display the results on browser screen.

Below is the code that I am trying to parse. But, it is throwing error `(SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1)`.

```
export default class ItemLister extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }
    componentDidMount() {

        axios
            .get('https://xxx.yyy.zzz/xyz/zyx/', {

                headers: {
                    'authorization':'Bearer XXXXXXXXX',
                    'X-Api-Key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',               
                },
                withCredentials: true

            })
            .then(response => {

                console.log(response.data) // it gets the correct response and printing in logs

                const persons = response.data;

                this.setState({ persons });

            }) 
            .catch (err => {
              console.log("error")
            });          
  }

  render() {
    return <ul>{this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}</ul>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ItemLister />, document.getElementById('root'))
registerServiceWorker()
```

I couldn't find fix for it. Can someone guide me whether the parsing of such json is correct or not and how to get the parsed results and displayed on screen?

Comment: Is staging really wrapped between backquote? Or normal quote?

Comment: Do you actually need to parse it as JSON? Is `response.data` already JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error occurs because you're trying to parse an `Object` instead of a `String`. Simply skip `JSON.parse` and set `result` to `response.data`:

```
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data) // it gets the correct response and printing in logs
  this.setState({ result: response.data });
})
```

And in you `render`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      { this.state.result &&
        this.state.result.staging &&
        this.state.result.staging.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)
      }
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is not giving error now. But, not displaying on screen in the browser.

Comment: Ok sure. Yes Added now